# How much rep does a veteran have?

Tags: discussion

So occasionally around the place (on Meta) I see "Since you are a veteran" or "Veterans have this privilege".

For example, [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/11598/186134).

How much rep does a user have to have to be considered a veteran?

Comment: define "veteran"

Comment: I don't know what instance or usage you are referring to, but in my book a veteran isn't based on how much rep you have, it is based on how long you have been here and how active you've been.

Comment: @Braiam That's what I'm asking! What is a veteran on SO?

Comment: 2k rep would definitely put you in the "regular user, doesn't need to know about every little badge" category.. Other than that, veteran doesn't have a solid "definition".

Comment: I think what Oded means in that answer is that you have a a fairly large amount of rep - time probably doesn't matter that much in this case, even though many people's rep increases over time. The boring way to look as this would be a dictionary - and since I don't think there have been any SE 'wars' as such (apart from some insistent post editors), a person with *'long experience in any particular activity'* could be the best definition. 'Veteran' could even refer to a [established user](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/established-user).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that "veteran" has to be taken in context of the conversation. For example, in [this conversation](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11592/how-can-we-encourage-3k-users-to-review-more-close-votes) "verteran" presumedy would  refer to users with both 3K + reputation and experience in reviewing close votes on SE.

Short answer - verteran implies not only reputation, but also some experience with the topic at hand.

You might also find the [privileges](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) page useful.

Comment: Veteran can also trump reputation, in the case of if I were a newbie here, but were actually extremely well versed in something like nginx (which I am since I package it).  But yes, this is an accurate assessment.